# import another (helper) class in Reacjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to write a helper class for like:

```
export default class A {
  constructor() {
    console.log(1);
  }
  test() {
    console.log(2);
  }
}
```

that I can use it in my component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import A from "./service/socket";

class Test extends Component {
  state = {
    counter: 0
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    A.test();
  };
}
```

how can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

`test` is a method on an *instance* of `A`. If you just want to create a collection of helper functions and don't actually need a *class*, export the functions directly from the module:

```
// ./service/socket
export function test() {
  console.log(2);
}

// somefile.js
import {test} from './service/socket';
test();
```

---

If you really need a class, you'd have to create an instance first, e.g.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import A from "./service/socket";

const instanceA = new A();

class Test extends Component {
  state = {
    counter: 0
  };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    instanceA.test();
  };
}
```

But you shouldn't use classes as bags of methods.

Comment: ah thank you. You said I shouldn't use classes as bags of methods. When I only use functions I am missing member attributes though?

Comment: I was just going off your example. Of course it's also OK to use a class if you have to.